# Trying to get log of specific course of a specific department in moodle

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to get log of courses in moodle by department wise.
Moodle showing all courses in log report which is difficult to understand because I have more than one department.
I want to get log by hierarchical structure.

here is Query moodle using to getting course list

```
public function get_course_list() {
    global $DB, $SITE;

    $courses = array();

    $sitecontext = context_system::instance();
    // First check to see if we can override showcourses and showusers.
    $numcourses = $DB->count_records("course");
    if ($numcourses < COURSE_MAX_COURSES_PER_DROPDOWN && !$this->showcourses) {
        $this->showcourses = 1;
    }

    // Check if course filter should be shown.
    if (has_capability('report/log:view', $sitecontext) && $this->showcourses) {
        if ($courserecords = $DB->get_records("course", null, "fullname", "id,shortname,fullname,category")) {
            foreach ($courserecords as $course) {
                if ($course->id == SITEID) {
                    $courses[$course->id] = format_string($course->fullname) . ' (' . get_string('site') . ')';
                } else {
                    $courses[$course->id] = format_string(get_course_display_name_for_list($course));
                }
            }
        }
        core_collator::asort($courses);
    }
    return $courses;
}
```